# build of ros fuerte colladadom fails on armhf - beaglebone

Tags: rosdep, beaglebone, ubuntu, rosmake, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I was following a [guide](http://quadrotordiaries.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/installing-ros-fuerte-on-beaglebone.html) on building ros for an armhf device (beaglebone) however ran into a problem in that my compiler failed when compiling the [level 2 packages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source#fuerte.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-rosinstall.Build_Higher-level.2BAC8-tools_.28Layer_2.29)

The compiler error is:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ivcon [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ivcon [PASS] [ 9.57 seconds ]                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                    
[ rosmake ] All 14 linesolladadom: 388.8 sec ]       [ 1 Active 4/102 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ROOT is: /home/ubuntu/ros/robot_model/colladadom
  mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/ros/robot_model/colladadom/include
  mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/ros/robot_model/colladadom/lib
  making it
  cd build/colladadom/dom && make -l1
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/ros/robot_model/colladadom/build/colladadom/dom'
  Compiling src/1.5/dom/domTypes.cpp to build/linux-1.5/obj/domTypes.o
  g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
  make[1]: *** [build/linux-1.5/obj/domTypes.o] Error 4
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/ros/robot_model/colladadom/build/colladadom/dom'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package colladadom written to: 4/102 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/ubuntu/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130321-191548/colladadom/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< colladadom [FAIL] [ 389.12 seconds ]                   
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package colladadom. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 5 packages with 1 failures.                                   
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/ubuntu/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130321-191548
```

Stackoverflow [says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103396/c11-g-4-7-internal-compiler-error) the `g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)` error is due to a lack of memory, which may be correct as the beagle bone has 250Mb, though the original guide did not mention anything on it being a problem.

Can anyone suggest a workaround or how to cross compile ros for armhf?

cheers

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58884/build-of-ros-fuerte-colladadom-fails-on-armhf---beaglebone/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this on other boards: when the compiler has to fetch so many things it runs out of memory, strange error messages are output.
To be sure of this just run `HTOP` or `TOP` in a terminal and observe the memory.

To get away with the compilation you need to increase your memory: either create or modify a swap file as [shown here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_more_swap.3F).

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-03-23**:
molto bene claudio! grazie!

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-16**:
Just wanted to say that 3 years later this answer helped me a lot! Thanks +1